# .NET 3.5 SP1 static linked

Tags: c#, .net, linker

I've coded an application that is used to troubleshoot different scenarios. It is using .NET 3.5 SP1 and I'd like to allow users to use the application from a USB drive.
Is it possible to static link this .NET version or to use it from the application directory like any other dll?

Comment: You mean, run it without .NET installed on the computer? No.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is a lot more than just a dll. At a minimum it loads a ton of stuff into the GAC and sets up some registry keys, I believe some system files are modified as well.

There are tools that will let you install .NET if it is not present, you should use one of these. Windows will also automatically install it if there is an internet connection, so you shouldn't have to worry about this too much.

Here is a reference from the MSDN [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6adeee3c-e139-4246-bf20-00e182e0e3db/run-a-net-application-without-installing-the-framework?forum=netfxsetup) that lists the versions of .NET your users may already have.

Comment: As I mentioned I want to run my application from a USB. Of course, this means that I don't want to install anything.

Comment: Right, my answer is trying to explain why this is not possible.